# robust and flexible 3d data structure

Tags: opengl, data-structures, 3d

I'm looking for a concept to store (in 3 dimensional euclidian space) faces, edges and vertex such that

- information (about relation) isn't duplicated
- queries for adjecent and neighboring faces/edges/vertex are fast
- the mesh is not limited to connected faces of the same winding

*definitions*

- neighbor of a face: the face that shares an edge with this face
- neighbor of a vertex: the vertex that is on the other end of an edge sharing that vertex
- adjecent edge: an edge that shares the same vertex of an endpoint with this edge

I have considered the Half-Edge data structure, but queries on it only really work when all connected faces have the same winding.

For instance, consider this pseudo code to access such related entities:

```
face.neighbors #the neighboring faces
face.edges #the edges shared by this face (in the right winding order)
face.verts #the vertex of that face (in the right winding order)
edge.v1, edge.v2 #the two vertex making up an edge
vertex.edges #the edges this vertex shares
vertex.neighbors # the neighbors of this vertex along each shared edge
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/), the Computational Geometry Algorithms Library.  You might be able to use something directly, or at least get some good ideas.  Half-edge sounds like a good idea; in my opinion, you should enforce uniform winding as much as possible.  It sounds like you're not interested in that, however.

One idea could be to retain a pair (one element for each winding) in the data structure for a face; this might give you enough flexibility to implement some kind of half-edge-like data structure on top of it, with good efficiency.

Comment: I do not want to tie queries to winding because it could be intentional that the face is "inverted" in the soup of other faces, yet still desirable to share vertices and be queryable.

Comment: If your language of choice is C++ and you aren't scared by extensive use of templates I recommend at least looking at CGAL. Otherwise it might not be the best choice. It's very C++.

Comment: I'm looking less for a particular library then for a general concept.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you also take a look at [OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org/). It is also heavy on the C++ template side like CGAL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be limited to manifold surfaces, winged-edge is it these days.  If "data about relation" is really your top priority then I guess you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a abstract about a data structure for 3d mesh. http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2006/Papers_2006/Short/E17-full.pdf

Answer (score -2):

> *Not so much a recommended structure but rather a 3D library used by a pro for computational task that can be built upon.*

Michael Garland, a research scientist with NVIDIA Research, have release his graphics library he uses for computational tasks on 3D models and meshes.

- [libgfx](http://mgarland.org/files/dist/libgfx-1.1.0-doc/index.html)
- [qslim](http://mgarland.org/software/qslim.html) a mesh simplification app based on libgfx (I have personally used it and ported [qvis](http://www.memention.com/qvis/) to MacOSX)

Comment: libgfx is anything but a data structure (no mention of mesh or data structure _anywhere_ in the documentation)

Comment: ok, sorry for that, thought it could be good to have a look at what a pro is using...or perhaps build upon...